# how to get the children of a deeply nested array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, mapping

I have this data

```
  const data = [
    {
      name: "Car",
      id: "19",
      count: "20",
      depth: "1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Wheel",
          id: "22",
          count: "3",
          depth: "2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "Engine",
              id: "101",
              count: "1",
              depth: "3",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "Engine and Brakes",
                  id: "344",
                  count: "1",
                  depth: "4",
                  children: []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Bike",
      id: "3",
      count: "12",
      depth: "1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "SpeedBike",
          id: "4",
          count: "12",
          depth: "2",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I want to pass in multiple category ids as follows ['101', '3'] and be able to only get the direct children of the passed category ids which should look like this:

```
[
  {
     name: "Engine and Brakes",
     id: "344",
     count: "1",
  },
  {
    name: "SpeedBike",
    id: "4",
    count: "12",
   }
]
```

If no category id is passed I want to be able to see the parent and the direct children as default. like below:

```
[
 {  
    name: "Car",
    id: "19",
    count: "20"
 },
 {
    name: "Wheel",
    id: "22",
    count: "3"
 },
 {
    name: "Bike",
    id: "3",
    count: "12",
 },
 {
    name: "SpeedBike",
    id: "4",
    count: "12"
 }
]
```

If the category id passed does not have children I want to return an empty array.:

```
[]
```

I want to avoid using `for` `foreach` and `while`. How can I achieve this? I have tried using `map` and `filter` but no luck. Can someone please help? What is the best approach to this?

I am using js and ts.

The nested array can be deep with multiple deep levels.

Comment: The fastest approach is with using `while`, you can also use recursion, however it's a bit more pricey. If `while` is okay I can post the answer

Comment: @wonderflame is there a way to avoid loops? are there any built in methods that can be used like map? filter?

Comment: I don't think there is anything built in to do that. All of the array methods will traverse the array itself and stop, which is not suitable for us

Comment: @wonderflame what about using json stringify and then using regex to search and then parsing it? 
will map and filter do it? also why is recursion pricey?
I wouldn't mind seeing it using a while

Comment: I don't think that `JSON.stringify` will be a good solution; of course, it is possible; however, it's not easy to understand for other devs. The recursive approach requires `O(logN)` extra space for call stack size. Basically, every call of the function takes some space in memory. Okay then, I'll put a while solution

Comment: Also, please update the description, you should have written `[101, 3]`, not `4` instead of `3`

Comment: @wonderflame oh yeah sorry my bad, will update it

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3vxjN) work for you?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `for`, `foreach` or `while`? Array methods like `.filter()`, `.map()`, `.reduce()` here are implicit loops anyway.

Comment: @NickParsons I prefer to use implicit loops instead `.filter()`, `.map()`, `.reduce()` can it be achieved using them?

Comment: No, since their stop condition is reaching the end of the array

Comment: If we try to use those methods we will have to also include recursion, if you don't want `while` which is not good in terms of performance

Comment: @wonderflame I am trying the `while` now.

Comment: @NickParsons whaat do you think the best approach to this would be?

Comment: @CEJ It depends what you're after, if you want something that's efficient, a `while` loop is probably your best bet. If you want something that's more functional/declarative then using something like `.map()`/`.flatMap()`/`.reduce()` would work, but you'll most likely end up doing additional iterations that aren't needed (so it won't be as efficient).

Comment: Is `['22', '101']` a valid input?

Comment: @NickParsons yes this is a valid input

Comment: @CEJ, so what do you think about my approach?

Comment: @NickParsons btw I'm from Australia as well :) 
Would you be able to please show me an approach using .map()/.flatMap()/.reduce()? I just wanted a more modern approach, maybe its not achievable?

Comment: @wonderflame quick question, is there a way to display the first children of each parent if no categoryids is passed?

Comment: @wonderflame cause if the categoryIds is empty I am getting no results

Comment: @CEJ If you use those methods though, the approach would utilise recursion as well as those methods (similar to what was posted previously but has now been removed). I don't think you can do it without recursion if you want to use array methods, as they only iterate a fixed number of times (the length of the array you called the method on), which you don't know in advance. Something like what wonderflame showed is a nice way.

Comment: @NickParsons oh makes sense, so I guess then that the while loop is my best call. and this is the best approach for any size of data correct?

Comment: @wonderflame if I don't pass in any categoryId can I display the first parent ands its direct children only?

Comment: `data[0].children`?

Comment: @wonderflame can you please take a look

Comment: @CEJ so only the first level? [parent, children, parent children]?

Comment: @wonderflame correct

Comment: @CEJ does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJxAZN) work?

Comment: @wonderflame I am getting Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add return [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wj8D2m)

Comment: @wonderflame thank you for this, do you want to post the answer here? 
I have a question though if the categoryid passed does not have children, then an empty array should be returned, example if I pass 4, then I should get an empty array

Comment: @wonderflame I have updated the description, can you please take a look.

Comment: I was waiting for your approval to post the answer. But it already returns an empty array if there is no child, no?

Comment: @wonderflame can you please take a look?

Comment: @NickParsons can you please advise

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253711/discussion-between-cej-and-wonderflame).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in functions to do that. Instead, there are two approaches that we can take: iterative and recursive.

The recursive approach requires O(logN) extra space for call stack size; thus, we will use the iterative approach.

Algorithm:

- If category ids are provided:

  - Populate stack with categories of the first level
  - While the stack is not empty:

    - Pop category from the stack
    - If category id is in the desired ids array:

      - Map through the category's children and retrieve the desired properties
    - Push children of the category to stack
- else:

  - Loop through the first level.
  - Push the parent and children of the parent.

Type for category:

```
type Category = {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  count: string;
  depth: string;
  children: Category[];
};
```

Implementation:

```
const getCategoriesChildren = (
  categoryIds: Category['id'][],
  categories: Category[],
) => {
  const foundChildren: Pick<Category, 'id' | 'count' | 'name'>[] = [];

  if (categoryIds.length === 0) {
    return categories.reduce<Pick<Category, 'id' | 'count' | 'name'>[]>(
      (acc, category) => {
        acc.push(mapCategory(category), ...category.children.map(mapCategory));
        return acc;
      },
      [],
    );
  }

  const stack = [...categories];

  while (stack.length) {
    const category = stack.pop();
    if (!category) continue;
    if (categoryIds.includes(category.id)) {
      foundChildren.push(
        ...category.children.map((childCategory) => ({
          name: childCategory.name,
          id: childCategory.id,
          count: childCategory.count,
        })),
      );
    }
    stack.push(...category.children);
  }

  return foundChildren;
};
```

Usage:

```
// [{
//   "name": "SpeedBike",
//   "id": "4",
//   "count": "12"
// }, {
//   "name": "Engine and Brakes",
//   "id": "344",
//   "count": "1"
// }] 
console.log(getCategoriesChildren(['101', '3'], data));

// [{
//   "name": "Car",
//   "id": "19",
//   "count": "20"
// }, {
//   "name": "Wheel",
//   "id": "22",
//   "count": "3"
// }, {
//   "name": "Bike",
//   "id": "3",
//   "count": "12"
// }, {
//   "name": "SpeedBike",
//   "id": "4",
//   "count": "12"
// }]
console.log(getCategoriesChildren([], data));
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/wj8D2m)

Comment: is there a way to get all children of the matched category_ids and not just the direct ones?