# how to show the children of specific category ids and flatten them in the end in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, hierarchy

I have this data

```
  const data = [
    {
      name: "Car",
      id: "19",
      count: "20",
      depth: "1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Wheel",
          id: "22",
          count: "3",
          depth: "2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "Engine",
              id: "101",
              count: "1",
              depth: "3",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "Engine and Brakes",
                  id: "344",
                  count: "1",
                  depth: "4",
                  children: []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Bike",
      id: "3",
      count: "12",
      depth: "1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "SpeedBike",
          id: "4",
          count: "12",
          depth: "2",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I want to pass in multiple category ids as follows ['22', '3'] and be able to get all the children of the passed category ids which should look like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "Engine",
    id: "101",
    count: "1",
  },
  {
    name: "Engine and Brakes",
    id: "344",
    count: "1",
  },
  {
    name: "SpeedBike",
    id: "4",
    count: "12",
  }
]
```

If no category id is passed I want to be able to see the parent and the direct children as default. like below:

```
[
 {  
    name: "Car",
    id: "19",
    count: "20"
 },
 {
    name: "Wheel",
    id: "22",
    count: "3"
 },
 {
    name: "Bike",
    id: "3",
    count: "12",
 },
 {
    name: "SpeedBike",
    id: "4",
    count: "12"
 }
]
```

If the category id passed does not have children I want to return an empty array.:

```
[]
```

I want to avoid using `for` `foreach` and `while`. How can I achieve this? I have tried using `map` and `filter` but no luck. Can someone please help? What is the best approach to this?

I am using js and ts.

The nested array can be deep with multiple deep levels.

Answer (score 0):

We are still going to use the [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76272181/21637817) described in your [previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76270550/how-to-get-the-children-of-a-deeply-nested-array-in-js). However, we are going to update the algorithm slightly.

Now stack will store categories with additional `isDesired?: boolean` prop, which indicates that this category is the descendant of the category with the id that we are looking for.
If the category's id is in `categoryIds` then we push its children in the stack with the `isDesired: true`.
We decide to put children  of category into `foundChildren` under the condition: if the category id is in `categoryIds` or `category.isDesired` is `true`

```
const mapCategory = (category: Category) => ({
  name: category.name,
  id: category.id,
  count: category.count,
});

const getCategoriesChildren = (
  categoryIds: Category['id'][],
  categories: Category[],
) => {
  const foundChildren: Pick<Category, 'id' | 'count' | 'name'>[] = [];

  if (categoryIds.length === 0) {
    return categories.reduce<Pick<Category, 'id' | 'count' | 'name'>[]>(
      (acc, category) => {
        acc.push(mapCategory(category), ...category.children.map(mapCategory));
        return acc;
      },
      [],
    );
  }

  const stack: (Category & { isDesired?: boolean })[] = [...categories];

  while (stack.length) {
    const category = stack.pop();
    if (!category) continue;

    const isDesiredCategory =
      categoryIds.includes(category.id) || category.isDesired;

    if (isDesiredCategory) {
      foundChildren.push(...category.children.map(mapCategory));
    }

    stack.push(
      ...(isDesiredCategory
        ? category.children.map((child) => ({ ...child, isDesired: true }))
        : category.children),
    );
  }

  return foundChildren;
};
```

[Playground with comments](https://tsplay.dev/w1xn2W)

Answer (score 0):

Call this function -

```
function GetFilteredOrNonFilteredData(data, stringofids = [])
{
const resolvedData = GetData(data);
if (stringofids.length <= 0) {
    return resolvedData.map(item => {
        delete item.parentid;
        delete item.depth;
        delete item.children;
        return item
    });
}
return resolvedData.filter((item) => {
    
    if(stringofids.some(i => item.parentid.includes(i))){
        delete item.parentid;
        delete item.depth;
        delete item.children;
        return item
    };
})
}
```

Include this function in the file -

```
function GetData(data) {
const allData = [];
function processItem(item, parentId) {
    item.parentid = parentId;
    allData.push(item);
    if (item.children.length > 0) {
        var newids = parentId.filter((i)=>{if(i>0){return i;}});
        newids.push(item.id);
        item.children.forEach(child => processItem(child, newids));
    }
}

data.forEach(item => {
    id = [0];
    processItem(item, id);
});

return allData;
}
```

Example -

```
console.log(GetFilteredOrNonFilteredData(data,["101","22"]));
```

Comment: This solution doesn't match the expected output at all. Check [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wk88jw)

Comment: I made the edit required , Thanks for reviewing

Comment: Still not the expected one. When you pass `22` it should give both `101` and `344`. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wyxxbm)

Comment: I got your point and made edits in the code again and again thanks for reviewing!